# Order of lifecycle events in Polymer.dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a problem with differences in order of lifecycle events in Polymer.dart

Events happen in different order when dart code is run in Dartium and when compiled JavaScript is run in Chrome.

I have 2 Polymer elements: Parent and Child and I added output in created and enteredView functions.

The output is:
Dartium:

```
ChildElement created
ChildElement enteredView. Variable value: InitMsg
ParentElement created
ParentElement enteredView
```

Chrome:

```
ChildElement created
ParentElement created
ParentElement enteredView
ChildElement enteredView. Variable value: InitMsg
```

The questions are:

- is this result completely arbitrary, or is there some order that can be relied upon?
- if a variable is assigned in Parent's created method, new value it is obviously not visible in Child's enteredView. I need to do some calculations based on new value. Is PathObserver in child the only solution to get notified of this assignment, or is there some moment in time/lifecycle callback happening after Parent's created() when this value is visible in child?

My code:

parentelement.dart:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('parent-element')
class ParentElement extends PolymerElement {
  @observable String msg = "InitMsg";

  ParentElement.created() : super.created() {
    print('Parent created');
    msg = "Changed msg";
  }

  @override
    void enteredView() {
      super.enteredView();
      print('ParentElement enteredView');     
    }


}
```

parentelement.html

```dart
<link rel="import" href="childelement.html">

<polymer-element name="parent-element">
  <template>    
    <div>      
      <span>Parent Msg: {{msg}}</span>
    </div>
    <child-element msg="{{msg}}"></child-element>    
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="parentelement.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

childelement.dart:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('child-element')
class ChildElement extends PolymerElement {
  @published String msg;

 ChildElement.created() : super.created() {
   print('ChildElement created');
 }

 @override
 void enteredView() {
   super.enteredView();
   print('ChildElement enteredView. Variable value: $msg');     
 }
}
```

childelement.html

```dart
<polymer-element name="child-element">
  <template>    
    <div>      
      <span>Child msg: {{msg}}</span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="childelement.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `created` constructor is not suitable if you want rely on the order they are called.
As far as I know the `polymerCreated` callback should be a better fit for you requirement.

I don' really know because <del>`enteredView`</del> `attached` fulfilled all my requirements and I therefore never used something else (<del>`entereView`</del> `attached` even provides two different slots for own code: 'before `super.attached()`' and 'after `super.attached()`')

Comment: +1, Do you happen to know why enteredView order is different: child first in dartium, parent first in Chrome?

Comment: As far as I know this has changed recently. Maybe in Chrome this relys on the polifill which might behave differently. I think you should file a bug anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added a link to this question to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and described it in a  blog post ( http://www.roberthartung.de/animatr-gui-structure-nesting-polymer-elements/ ). The trick for me was to put the `<link rel="import">`-statements not in a central place, but into the custom elements itself. My App only has one import for my custom GUI element. The GUI imports its direct custom child elements and so on.

Hope this helps
Robert

Comment: According to the post from jmesserly from April 21 in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/Dog6SQ6oy84) `<link rel="import" href="...">` should be kept outside the `<polymer-element>` tag otherwise it won't work when built to JavaScript.